# Resource Timeline Database Design

Tags: events, google-cloud-firestore, database-design, calendar, timeline

I have to program a web-app that allows to book spaces in a gym, but I don't know how to manage the database, should I create for each activity a calendar with all the available hours and assign a counter to each hour? I am working with Cloud Firestore Database and I think that reading all that information to present a table of available hours could cost too much money. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

One way that has worked for me is to create these tables in the database:

1. TABLE Timeslot
2. TABLE Attendee
3. TABLE Gymclass

`Gymclass` links to `ManyToManyField(Timeslot)`

`Timeslot` links to `ManyToManyField(Attendee)`

Intuitively, this means that each `gymclass` has many `timeslot`s. Each `Timeslot` is say a one-hour slot of time. Each `Timeslot` has many `Attendee`s attached to it.

Then you can query `Timeslot` to provide the timetable, the classes and the attendees.